# Get user input and show on Turtle Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make a turtle Keyboard game where you need to type the correct letters to win.
This is my so far code:

```
import turtle
from english_words import english_words_lower_alpha_set
import time
import random


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width = 1200, height = 800)
wn.title("Keyboard Typer")
wn.bgcolor("#9bf6ff")


floor = turtle.Turtle()
floor.speed(0)
floor.shape("square")
floor.hideturtle()
floor.color("#fdffb6")
floor.penup()
floor.shapesize(stretch_wid = 10, stretch_len = 60)
floor.goto(0, -310)
floor.showturtle()

sun = turtle.Turtle()
sun.speed(0)
sun.shape("circle")
sun.hideturtle()
sun.color("yellow")
sun.penup()
sun.shapesize(stretch_wid = 3, stretch_len = 3)
sun.goto(-500, 270)
sun.showturtle()

text = turtle.Turtle()
text.hideturtle()
text.color("black", "#caffbf")
text.shape("square")
text.speed(0)
text.penup()
text.goto(0, 390)
text.showturtle()




List = list(english_words_lower_alpha_set)
for Numbers in range(0, 5):
    text.clear()
    text.goto(0, 390)
    text.showturtle()    
    Wordies = random.choice(List)
    for i in range(0, 20):
        y = text.ycor()
        y -= 20
        text.sety(y)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    
    text.write(Wordies, move = True, align = "center", font = ("Arial", 30, "normal"))
    text.hideturtle()
    time.sleep(5)




while True:
    wn.update()
```

This is the Result:
[image: This is the Result]

However, I want a text box or something similar on the yellow rectangle.
Want Input with text box:
[image: Want Input with text box]

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See also [`textinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput) for collecting input. It's a pop-up window though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes.

Since the "turtle" uses Tkinter to draw all graphics, you can add widgets from Tkinter itself directly to the turtle's canvas.
Here is a code:

```
import turtle
import time
from english_words import english_words_lower_alpha_set
import random
import tkinter as tk

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=1200, height=800)
wn.title("Keyboard Typer")
wn.bgcolor("#9bf6ff")

floor = turtle.Turtle()
# some tkinter
# canvas = floor.getscreen().cv
# or
canvas = wn.cv
#                    x and y
canvas.create_window(30, 30, tags=["entry"], window=tk.Entry(None, ))
floor.speed(0)
floor.shape("square")
floor.hideturtle()
floor.color("#fdffb6")
floor.penup()
floor.shapesize(stretch_wid=10, stretch_len=60)
floor.goto(0, -310)
floor.showturtle()

sun = turtle.Turtle()
sun.speed(0)
sun.shape("circle")
sun.hideturtle()
sun.color("yellow")
sun.penup()
sun.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=3)
sun.goto(-500, 270)
sun.showturtle()

text = turtle.Turtle()
text.hideturtle()
text.color("black", "#caffbf")
text.shape("square")
text.speed(0)
text.penup()
text.goto(0, 390)
text.showturtle()

List = list(english_words_lower_alpha_set)
for Numbers in range(0, 5):
    text.clear()
    text.goto(0, 390)
    text.showturtle()
    Wordies = random.choice(List)
    for i in range(0, 20):
        canvas.update()
        canvas.update_idletasks()
        y = text.ycor()
        y -= 20
        text.sety(y)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    text.write(Wordies, move=True, align="center", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
    text.hideturtle()
    time.sleep(5)



# while True:
#     wn.update()
```

So, I added an "Entry" widget to the canvas. The first and the second argument is x and y respectfully. For further modifications, you can visit this [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm).